# NServiceBus transfering message from pub queue to sub queue

Tags: nservicebus

I am getting a little confused with NServiceBus.  It seems like a lot of examples that I see, they always use publish() and subscribe().  What I am trying to do is that I have a publisher that polling from its queue and distributes the message to subscriber’s queue.  The messages are being generated by other application and the body of message will contain a text, which will be parsed later.

Do I still need to call publish() and subsribe() to transfer the messages from publisher's queue to subscriber's queue?  The way I understood was that I only need to configure the queue names in both config file and call LoadAllMessages() on subscriber side, will take above scenario.  I don't even have to handle the message on the subscriber side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Publisher will still need to call Publish.  What this does is the Publisher then looks into Subscription Storage to find out who is interested in that message type. It then will send a message to each Subscriber.  On the Subscriber side you need to implement message handlers to do something with those messages.  This is done via implementing the IHandleMessages<T> interface in the Subscriber assembly.  NSB will discover this and autowire everything up.  Be aware by default, the Subscriber will subscriber to all message types.  If you want to only subscribe to certain messages, use the .DoNotAutoSubscribe setting in the manual configuration.